# find probability of n people in a class of x share the same birthday using monte carlo simulation in java

Tags: java, montecarlo, birthday-paradox

As the problem states, i must use monte carlo(randomness) to solve the question given. I am running the simulation 1,000,000 times.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MonteCarlo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please enter size of the class: ");
       int classSize = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Please enter the amount of people who share the same birthday: ");
       int birthPpl = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.println("calculate the probability that "+birthPpl+" people share the same Birthday in a class size of "+classSize);
      
       sc.close();
       
       int birthdays [] = new int[classSize];
       int simulations = 0;
       int success=0;
       for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
            simulations++;
            if(Collision(birthdays)>=birthPpl){
                success++;
            }
       }
       System.out.println(success+" "+simulations);
       System.out.println("Answer: "+ (success*100)/simulations + "%");
    }

    public static int Collision(int birthday[]){
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i=1; i<birthday.length; i++){
            birthday[i]= rand.nextInt(365);
        }

        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<birthday.length; i++){
            for(int j= i+1; j<birthday.length; j++){
                
                if(birthday[i]==birthday[j]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

As per a couple of psuedo code solutions i have seen online i have tried looping through the size of the class x and inserting in a random birthday. then comparing birthdays , reducing the birthdays i look through by 1 each time. I then check the number of collisions against the amount sof ppl who should a birthday , if it is greater or equal to it than i increase the count. i have been given sample imput 20 and 2 which should give 41 % but my program gives eithe 7 or 8 %

What's the problem, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: It looks like if exactly two people in your sample share a birthday, then `Collision` will return 1.  But in your main loop, if your inputs are 20 and 2, you'll only count a success when `Collision` returns 2 or more (which would happen if there are two pairs of birthday sharers, or three people who share a birthday).  There's no way that happens 41% of the time.

Comment: Also, it loops for one less (`for int i = 1;..` should be `for (int i = 0; ...`).

Comment: @rzwitserloot I don't think that will actually affect the calculation.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem By sheer luck, indeed, locking the birthday of at most 1 classmate to a specific date (in this case, jan 1st), wouldn't. But leaving that bug in there means further experimentation with this code will then start running into this. With monte carlo simulations, things are complicated - normally you can just debug and follow along with your algorithm, check for problems. With MC, you may not see such stochastic errors.

Comment: "find probability of n people in a class of x" -- Is that *exactly* `n`? Or is it at least n?  Suppose, for example, `classSize` is 25, and `birthPpl` is 2. Suppose there are 3 people that share a birthday. How should your program handle that?  What if there are 3 pairs of shared birthdays?

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use the [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#Random()) and [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap()) classes. [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) will take the key, a birthday in this case, then a default value of `1`, and continues to add `1` to the existing value which is returned and compared to `x`. Then success is appropriately updated.  The Random class provides a variety of methods to return random numbers and is usually preferred over `Math.random.`

```
double success = 0;
int tests = 1_000_000;

// instantiate a Random class for selecting the next birthday
Random r = new Random();

// a map to hold the frequency count of same birthdays
Map<Integer,Integer> birthdays = new HashMap<>();


int n = 23;
int x = 2;

for(int i=0; i< tests; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
       if (birthdays.merge(r.nextInt(365), 1, Integer::sum) >= x) {
           success++;
           break;
       }
   }
   // clear the map for the next run
   birthdays.clear();
}
```

Using [System.out.printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) facilitates formatting the output.

```
System.out.printf("probability = %4.1f%%%n", (success/tests) * 100);
```

prints something like the following:

```
probability = 50.7%
```

Answer (score -2):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Birthday {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt(); // class size
        int x = sc.nextInt(); // people who share the same birthday
        double tests = 1_000_000;
        double success = 0;


        // fills array of birthdays and breaks out when x amount of people share 
        // a birthday. then we find the % of successes.
        for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
            int[] year = new int[365];

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                int birthday = (int) (Math.random() * 365);
                year[birthday]++;
                if (year[birthday] >= x) {
                    success++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Math.round(success * 100 / tests));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a "code dump" answer: Code with no explanation. I guess the O/P doesn't mind, since the answer came from the O/P.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service - it's about providing clear answers to problems people are facing.  So answers that contain code but no explanation aren't really welcome on Stack Overflow.  I have voted to delete this.